# How to implement a backend for GraphQL connections?

Tags: sql, sorting, pagination, graphql

In GraphQL the recommended way for pagination is to use connections as described [here](https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/). I understand the reasons and advantages of this usage but I need an advice how to implement it.

The server side of the application works on top of a SQL database (Postgres in my case). Some of the GraphQL connection fields have optional argument to specify sorting. Now with knowing the sorting columns and a cursor from the GraphQL query, how can I build an SQL query? Of course it should be efficient - if there is a SQL index index for the combination of sorting columns it should be used.

The problem is that SQL doesn't know anything like GraphQL cursors - we can't tell it to select all rows after certain row. There is just WHERE, OFFSET and LIMIT. From my point of view it seems I need to firstly select a single row based on the cursor and then build a second SQL query using the values of the sorting columns in that row to specify a complicated WHERE clause - not sure if the database would use index in that case.

*What bothers me is that I could not find any article on this topic. Does it mean that SQL database is not usually used when implementing a GraphQL server? What database should be used then? How are GraphQL queries to connection fields usually transformed to queries for the underlying database?*

EDIT: [This](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/issues/94#issuecomment-232410564) is more or less what I came up with myself. The problem is how to extend it to support sorting as well and how to implement it efficiently using database indexes.

Answer (score -1):

The trick here is that, as the server implementer, the cursor can be literally any value you want encoded as a string.  Most examples I've seen have been base64-encoded for a bit of opacity, but it doesn't have to be.  (Try base64-decoding the cursors from the Star Wars examples in your link, for example.)

Let's say your GraphQL schema looks like

```graphql
enum ThingColumn { FOO BAR }
input ThingFilter {
  foo: Int
  bar: Int
}
type Query {
  things(
    filter: ThingFilter,
    sort: ThingColumn,
    first: Int,
    after: String
  ): ThingConnection
}
```

Your first query might be

```graphql
query {
  things(filter: { foo: 1 }, sort: BAR, first: 2) {
    edges {
      node { bar }
    }
    pageInfo {
      endCursor
      hasNextPage
    }
  }
}
```

This on its own could fairly directly translate into an SQL query like

```sql
SELECT bar FROM things WHERE foo=1 ORDER BY bar ASC LIMIT 2;
```

Now as you iterate through each item you can just use a string version of its offset as its cursor; that's totally allowed by the spec.

```json
{
  "data": {
    "things": {
      "edges": [
        { "node": { "bar": 17 } },
        { "node": { "bar": 42 } }
      ],
      "pageInfo": {
        "endCursor": "2",
        "hasNextPage": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then when the next query says `after: "2"`, you can turn that back into an SQL `OFFSET` and repeat the query.

If you're trying to build a generic GraphQL interface that gets translated to reasonably generic SQL queries, it's impossible to create indexes such that every query is "fast".  Like other cases, you need to figure out what your common and/or slow queries are and `CREATE INDEX` as needed.  You might be able to limit the options in your schema to things you know you can index:

```graphql
type Other {
  things(first: Int, after: String): ThingConnection
}
```

```graphql
query OtherThings($id: ID!, $cursor: String) {
  node(id: $id) {
    ... on Other {
      things(first: 100, after: $cursor) { ... FromAbove }
    }
  }
}
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM things WHERE other_id=? ORDER BY id LIMIT ?;
```

```sql
CREATE INDEX things_other ON things(other_id);
```

Comment: Sorry but this is actually a very bad answer. The reason for connections and cursors is to prevent the downsides of offset-based pagination so using offset as cursor completely negates the point. Read this article for details: https://blog.apollographql.com/explaining-graphql-connections-c48b7c3d6976

Comment: _reads_ If you have a plain SQL data store, what _would_ you encode in the cursor?  I wouldn't try to hold a client cursor object open across multiple HTTP transactions, and if you don't do that, aren't you forced to repeat the query (and get potentially different answers)?

Comment: The cursor is usually encoded ID of the entity. Since I don't have experience with connections yet, I don't know what else could be used there. But from what I've read it's recommended for the cursors to not be dependent on other parameters like sorting and conditions - each node should always has the same cursor. This pretty much forces the cursor to be ID I think.

Repeating a query is a responsibility of the client, not the server.

Comment: I would expect a cursor value to be consistent across repeated calls to the same query, but I wouldn't necessarily expect it to be consistent across different queries.  [The spec says how to apply cursors at query time](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm#sec-Pagination-algorithm) but is silent about their format.  A node ID would be permitted, but not required; an SQL query that used a node ID as a cursor but sorted on some other field would be a good additional answer to this question.